# Matching Javascript Array to Java list

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, angular

I am making a POST request from my frontend (Angular) to my backend (Java). The post request is sent as a JSON object (consisting of multiple arrays) and in Java, should be matched to an object where the arrays are intended to be lists. Here's an example code to represent the problem since this is not the actual code as it belongs to work and do not want any confidentiality issues so this is simply to represent the issue as close to the original code as possible (worth noting that there are many schools stored and for argument's sake, they can be uniquely identified by their students and lessons taught and using this info, we want to get the classrooms present at that school):

Angular service api call:

```
getSchool(students, lessons): Promise<School> {
  return this.http.post('sampleurl/classroom', JSON.stringify({students:students, lessonsTaught:lessons}), {headers:this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => <School>res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Angular School model:

```
export class School {
  public students:any;
  public lessonsTaught:string[];
  public classrooms:string[];

  constructor() {}
}
```

Java School Object:

```
public class School {
  private List<Student> students;
  private List<String> lessonsTaught;
  private List<String> classrooms;

  public School() {}
  
  public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    students = this.students;
  }

  public List<Stream> getLessonsTaught() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setLessonsTaught(List<String> lessonsTaught) {
    lessonsTaught = this.lessonsTaught;
  }

  public List<String> getClassrooms() {
    return classrooms;
  }

  public void setClassroom(List<String> classroom) {
    classroom = this.classroom;
  }
```

Java SearchSchool Object:

```
public class SearchSchool {
  private List<String> students;
  private List<String> lessonsTaught;

  public School() {}
  
  public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    students = this.students;
  }

  public List<Stream> getLessonsTaught() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setLessonsTaught(List<String> lessonsTaught) {
    lessonsTaught = this.lessonsTaught;
  }
```

Java endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="sampleurl/classroom", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public School(@RequestBody SearchSchool searchSchool) {
  return service.getSchool(searchSchool);
}
```

So effectively, I am using the SearchSchool object in Java to uniquely identify the school and return it. However, the arrays being passed to the endpoint, don't seem to be matched to lists like the SearchSchool object requires (I have put a breakpoint on the entry in the endpoint and it is not even being executed). Having played around with the code a bit, the matching of the student's string array in the Angular to the student's string list in Java seems to be working fine and the issue seems to be matching the array of lessons taught to a list of lessons taught which gives me the following runtime errors the Developer's console in Chrome:

```
An error occurred syntaxError: service.ts: 163
Unexpected token A in JSON at position o
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (http.ess.js:796)
at duration service.ts:54
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:365)
at object.onInvoke (core.ess.js:4145)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:364)
at zone.run (zone.js:125)
at zone.js:760
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
at object.on InvokeTask (core.ess.js:4136)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593)
at XMLHttpRequest. ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464)
```

and:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): core.es5.js:1085
Unexpected token A in JSON at position o
at resolvePromise (zone.js:683) [angular]
at :8080/gar-app/polyfis:7034:17 [angular)
at object.onInvokeTask (core.ess.js:4136) [angular]
```

Does anyone know why matching from the array in the frontend to the list in the backend is causing such a problem?

Comment: Inspect the request in the browser console, is either the request or the response invalid json?

Comment: console.log `res` before returning `<School>res.json()`. Your response may not be what you are expection

Comment: @luk2302 The request does not seem to contain the JSON at all

Answer (score 0):

It is because mismatching of field name in frontend and backend

In frontend you are passing lessons and in backend you are expecting lessonsTaught

Modifying any one to make the code work

Frontend will look like this after a change

```
getSchool(students, lessons): Promise<School> {
  return this.http.post('sampleurl/classroom', JSON.stringify({students:students, lessonsTaught:lessons}), {headers:this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => <School>res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: no this is a `JSON.parse` error. `<School>` is just at compile time and wont throw mismatch error

Comment: You are mentioning the endpoint is not even hit right?

Comment: No I am saying the endpoint may not be sending valid json or maybe sending some sort of error...

Comment: The matching of the students string array in the Angular to the students string list in Java seems to be working fine and the issue seems to be matching the array of lessons taught to a list of lessons taught - You may try the change

Comment: Except.. mapping happens _after JSON.parse_ and that is what is throwing error. Either way OP needs to specify what `res` is returned

Comment: You are right in that it should be lessonsTaught, not lessons, in my actual code this isn't an issue as all names match as they should, this was just an error on my part when typing up this question and has been edited accordingly (thanks for bringing it to my attention).

Comment: Yes that's correct, the endpoint is never hit.

Comment: @mdaabis check whether the student and lessons are array of string before sending it

Comment: @mdaabis try without JSON.stringify()

Comment: gah.. You were talking about the request from angular. Sorry. I need coffee

Comment: I don't think anything is returned since the endpoint is never hit @SurajRao

Comment: @mdaabis I suggest you use a rest client to hit your API separately and check the response first and then try in your frontend. Also check if your URL and request format are correct. etc..

Comment: @SurajRao I tried using Postman and the endpoint was hit and returned exactly what I was expecting.

Comment: @SurajRao excuse me, I was wrong. When I edited the code to identify what the issue is (essentially I commented out all references to lessons taught in the frontend), I got the expected response returned. However, when I uncommented it, res returned an "Access Blocked for IP 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" error message. Why is this happening only for lessons taught?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an object instead JSON, just remove JSON.stringify()

```
getSchool(students, lessons): Promise<School> {
  return this.http.post('sampleurl/classroom', {students:students,lessonsTaught:lessons}, {headers:this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => <School>res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```